# The links doesnt work on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, css

I had the problem with mobile menu on Iphone. It did not appear over the slider(it works fine on the other devices + on the emulator in google developer tools). So I added -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px) to class of menu(I've got no clue why it works, I found the solution on the net). 
Now I have got the problem with the links on the menu. It doesn't work only on iphone. Moreover it works fine on the emulator. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a transform without webkit?

e.g.

```
div {
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
}
```

Comment: I only added -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px); to menu class.

Comment: try to add the other two transforms with the same values like my example